# Unsure how to perform action if all form inputs do NOT contain specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is more of a question on how to approach this scenario.

I have a form, and I need to perform an action if *any* form input contains ".ca", "canada" or "canadian", but I also need to reverse that action if the fields do NOT contain these strings. Ideally, this would action would trigger (if needed) as the form is completed rather than when submit is clicked.

My code to check for ".ca", "canada", or "canadian"

```
var optInFieldIsVisible = false;
var optInField = jQuery( 'input[name*="email"]' );

jQuery("*").find('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if (/.ca$|canada|canadian/i.test( jQuery(this).val() ) ) {
        optInFieldIsVisible = true;
        optInField.closest( '.formField' ).show();
            // show special form field because reference to canada is present
    }
    else {
        if (optInFieldIsVisible == false) {
            optInField.closest( '.formField' ).hide();
            // hide special form field because reference to canada is removed
    }
 });
```

The problem with the above code is that it has no condition that is ever valid for the special field will never re-hide once it is activated.

If I remove the "if (optInFieldIsVisible == false)" under the else-condition the field will show and hide properly if the user works within the currently selected input, BUT it will then re-hide as soon as anything is typed into the next input (since the regex returns false in the now-selected new form input).

Clearly a flag variable isn't the solution, and some sort of counter variable I also can't see as working here. Does anyone have pointers?

EDIT:
See live demo http://jsbin.com/toyin/1/edit

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle to make your question more visually understandable?

Comment: I've added a jsbin. Sorry... should have included that initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but this may be what you want:

```
var optInFieldIsVisible = false;
var optInField = jQuery( 'input[name*="email"]' );

jQuery("*").find('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if (/.ca$|canada|canadian/i.test( jQuery(this).val() && !optInFieldIsVisible ) ) {
        optInFieldIsVisible = true;
        optInField.closest( '.formField' ).show();
            // show special form field because reference to canada is present
    }
    else if (optInFieldIsVisible){
            optInFieldIsVisible = false;
            optInField.closest( '.formField' ).hide();
            // hide special form field because reference to canada is removed
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. The challenge of getting the optInField to re-hide when the if condition is not met remains though. I'm hoping the jsbin I added helps, and thank you for taking a look.

Comment: do you want the email input to be hidden when the condition is not met?

Comment: The checkbox is the input I am hoping to show or hide

Comment: well the checkbox is getting hidden and visible in your jsbin!

Comment: Because I have changed the fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/xojubaxo/1/edit), is it the thing you want to do?

```
var optInFieldIsVisible = false;
var optInField = jQuery( 'input[name*="opt-in"]' );
optInField.closest( 'div.formField' ).hide();

jQuery("*").find('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if (/.ca$|canada|canadian/i.test( jQuery(this).val() ) ) {
        optInFieldIsVisible = true;
        optInField.closest( 'div.formField' ).show();
    }
    else {
        optInFieldIsVisible = false;
        optInField.closest( 'div.formField' ).hide();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with to address this. Added a new function:

```
/* clear required field on focusout if triggers are removed from all fields */
jQuery("*").find('input').focusout(function(){
    var eList = []; 
    jQuery("*").find('input').each( function() { 
        if ( /.ca$|canada|canadian/i.test( jQuery(this).val() ) == false ) {
            eList.push(false);
            }
        else {
            eList.push(true);
        }
    })
    if ( jQuery.inArray(true, eList )==-1 ) {
        optInField.closest( '.formField' ).hide();
    }
})
```

Also removed the else statement from my original code, as that was no longer needed with the above added. See http://jsbin.com/toyin/3/edit